# Creating new list on Etsy

Tags: php, api, oauth, etsy

I am trying to create a new listing on Etsy.

1. I used oauth to authenticate and got
   `OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY`
   and
   `OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET`
2. I check it with this code and I got return og all the seller data, so everything is ok with the OAuth.

   ```
   $oauth = new OAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
   $oauth->setToken("key","secret"); 

   try {
    $data = $oauth->fetch("http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/__SELF__", null, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET);
    $json = $oauth->getLastResponse();
    print_r(json_decode($json, true));

   } catch (OAuthException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    error_log(print_r($oauth->getLastResponse(), true));
    error_log(print_r($oauth->getLastResponseInfo(), true));
    exit;
   }
   ```
3. I am trying to crate a new listings. First i managed to create a new listing through the api browser on the production. Now, i want to create a new listing through PHP. This is what i did, and it return my error:

This is my code:

```
$oauth = new OAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);

$oauth->setToken("key","secret");

try {
 $url = "http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings";

 $params = array('description' => 'thisisdesc','materials' => 'yes','price'=>"5.99"
 ,'quantity'=>"2",'shipping_template_id'=>"52299",'shop_section_id'=>"1"
 ,'title'=>"thisistitle",'category_id'=>"i_did",'who_made'=>"5.99"
 ,'is_supply'=>"1",'when_made'=>"2010_2012");


 $oauth->fetch($url, $params, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
 print_r(json_decode($json, true));

} catch (OAuthException $e) {

 print_r($e);

 error_log($e->getMessage());
 error_log(print_r($oauth->getLastResponse(), true));
 error_log(print_r($oauth->getLastResponseInfo(), true));
 exit;
}
```

I get the response of:

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 403, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect) 
This method not accessible to restricted API key.
```

Comment: Hmm, do a web search on "Etsy restricted API key". I wonder if you have made too many requests to the service, and your key has been put into a sin-bin? Check their FAQ or support pages.

Comment: no, i didnt make to many requests. when i create a request to the http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/__SELF__" it is working.

Comment: Hi, how did you get on with this? Any luck?

Comment: yes, i contact them for geting full access. for more information visit the google group https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/etsy-api-v2/axIua3d58eY

Comment: Have you found solution fir this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, [here's the answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/etsy-api-v2/De4eIO0ELGQ/s4UWhEfXde0J). From an Etsy developer:

> Your API was not yet approved for full API access.  I've fixed that, so you should be able to use those methods now.

Hence, get in touch with the firm, and ask for your key to be approved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still developing your application you can create listings without gaining full API access, so long as the shop is on your account. Make sure you parse in `listings_w` as a permission scope when making the first OAUTH request. I have altered the example provided by ETSY in the code below.

```
    // instantiate the OAuth object
    // OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY and OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET are constants holding your key and   secret
    // and are always used when instantiating the OAuth object 
    $oauth = new OAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);

    // make an API request for your temporary credentials
    $req_token = $oauth->getRequestToken("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oaut/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r%20listings_w", 'oob');

    print $req_token['login_url']."\n";`
```

Notice the `scope=email_r%20listings_r%20listings_w;`

Hope this helps